# Constant int incement

Tags: c, pointers

Consider below two cases.
case1: compiler error --> error: increment of read-only variable ‘x’

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    main()
    {
    const int x=5;
    printf("%d",++x);
    }
```

case2: Ran successfully with output 6. why?

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   main()
   {
   const int x=5;
   int *ptr=&x;
   ++(*ptr);
   printf("%d",x);
   }
```

Comment: The second one leads to *undefined behavior*. You use a pointer to non-constant `int` to modify a constant `int`. A good compiler should warn about it, and if it doesn't then you should turn on more warnings.

Comment: warning: initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type

Comment: So the case2 should be int const *ptr=&x to get the same behavior as we got in case1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int *ptr=&x;` is a constraint violation, i.e. an "error", invalid code. C language does not support implicit conversion of `const int *` type to `int *` type. Your compiler surely issued a diagnostic message for this.

After that diagnostic message your program's behavior is no longer defined by C language, assuming your compiler somehow agreed to compile it. Many C compilers can be configured to refuse to compile this code, even if they accept it in default mode.

You could force the conversion by using a cast

```
int *ptr = (int *) &x;
```

This would get rid of the above constraint violation. The compilers would now have to accept your code (with some caveats). But after that modification, the attempt to do `++*ptr` would trigger undefined behavior, because it is an attempt to modify a `const` object.

Comment: So the case2 should be int const *ptr=&x to get the same behavior as we got in case1

Comment: @Vijay S B: Yes, that's one way to do it. You could also force an explicit conversion (see above) getting rid of the error, but running into UB instead.